# Amazon Ec2 - Creating a private AMI

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have a quick rhetorical question. I want to create an AMI from my EC2 instance but I want it to be strictly private since it will contain my configs and SSH keys. When creating AMI via the EC2 dashboard I can't see any option to make it private.

So, my two questions are:

- How can I secure my created AMI so it isn't visible to anyone else
- Is it secure enough to store my SSH key on it without worrying about

Comment: Never put your credentials on the machine or bundle it as AMI. You might forget that you have them there. Use Roles (part of IAM) instead.

Comment: Can this work with SSH keys though @Guy

Comment: The SSH keys are only put on the instance when you launch it. It is not part of the AMI.

Comment: When I save them on the drive and create an AMI on it, it should still be there through right?

Comment: Only the public key is put on the instance by EC2, only you have the private part of the key. Anyway once an instance is launched from the AMI, the new public key will replace the one that you had there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because they're private by default, and sharing is the option you have to add later. [The documentation about creating a sharable/paid AMI demonstrates this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AESDG-chapter-paidamis.html), but in general the process for creating a non-private AMI is:

1. Make a private AMI
2. Share it.

   - Associate a product-code with the AMI through `ec2-modify-image-attribute --product-code` or a similar API call.
   - Modify the launch permissions through `ec2-modify-image-attribute --launch-permissions` or similar API call.
3. Profit!

Comment: Thank you. Can I trust the security of the private AMI with my SSH key and code do you think? I know it's quite an open eneded question but I would be interested to hear your response.

Comment: @JamesWillson That's an answer you have to ask yourself. In theory, Amazon employees have access to the storage your images are kept on and can read it out. If that's not a risk you want to take, AWS is not the platform for you.